# Using one tables values as another table's columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know how to explain what I want with words, so I've attached an image explaining it:

[image]

Which command should I write in SQL to do this?

I don't know what else stackexchange wants me to do to post a question, so I've added this sentence.

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL for this. Which DBMS are you  using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Do you have known numbers of types or can it be from 1 to n?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select set_id, 
       num, 
       case when type_id = 1 then id end as id_1,
       case when type_id = 2 then id end as id_2,
       case when type_id = 3 then id end as id_3
from your_table
group by set_id, num
```

Comment: This will work. Pivot is just a glorified case statement. Not sure why this was down voted.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm complete newbie, but I see that "id" column's not selected at all. Then how will it's values appear in wanted table? 

Maybe I simply don't undersatnd something..